# Xamarin.Forms - app working in uwp but not in android "The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread"

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As described in the title, I'm working on a xamarin app, something like a dynamic image gallery. What I did so far works in uwp, but Android gives this error: "A unhandled exception occurred. No compatible code running. The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread". I suppose it is some bug in a code because a newly created app works fine both in uwp and in android.

Xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Inżynierka"
         x:Class="Inżynierka.MainPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="MainView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

code behind:

```
public class MainPageCode : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel.CellViewModel> Cells { get; set; }
    public MainPageCode ()
    {
        Cells = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel.CellViewModel>();
        ListView MainView = new ListView();
        this.Title = "Inżynierka";
        MainView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
        Cells.Add(new ViewModel.CellViewModel { Name = "Test 1", Type = "Image", Image = "Test1.jpg" });
        Cells.Add(new ViewModel.CellViewModel { Name = "Test 2", Type = "Image", Image = "Test2.png" });
        Cells.Add(new ViewModel.CellViewModel { Name = "Test 3", Type = "Image", Image = "Test3.jpg" });
        MainView.ItemsSource = Cells;
        Content = MainView;
    }
    public class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public CustomCell()
        {
            //instantiate items in views
            var Image = new Image();
            var NameLabel = new Label();
            var Frame = new Frame() { OutlineColor = Color.Black };
            var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke };

            //set bindings
            NameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            Image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));
            Image.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            Image.HeightRequest = 600;
            Image.WidthRequest = 600;
            NameLabel.FontSize = 24;

            //add views to the view hierarchy
            horizontalLayout.Children.Add(NameLabel);
            horizontalLayout.Children.Add(Image);

            //add to parent view
            View = horizontalLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

app.xaml.cs:

```
public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage();
        MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPageCode());
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Sure, I'll upload solution where this issue exists later today.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT https://github.com/KonradCzarny/In-ynierka/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been caused by using "ż" - polish diacritic character in assembly name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add that images to each platform location? e.g. drawable folder in android

Comment: Yes. They are in Resources/Drawable on Andoird and Assets on UWP

Comment: Why did you call MainPage and MainPageCode in your App.cs? How are you separating view from code behind? Did you have a viewmodel? to your page?

Comment: I had it in 2 separate files, but i changed it to just one:  MainPage = new Inżynierka.MainPage(); now, still the same.